# Is there a way to use only Bootstrap's 5 grid system?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

In older versions of Bootstrap there was an option to build custom Bootstap setup, including only Bootstraps's grid system.

Is there a way to build custom Bootstrap 5 setup, which would provide support for the grid system only from Bootstrap?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just like Bootstrap 4, in Bootstrap 5 you can use `bootstrap-grid.css` or minimized file downloaded from its [Contents](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/contents/#css-files) page. It includes only the grid system and related flex utilities.

Note that it doesn't include [Reboot pre-styles](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/reboot/), so you might notice some style changes if you switches from the full bootstrap bundle to this.

[image]